# Monitoring / logging bandwidth usage per KVM on SmartOS?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, smartos

Usually on a KVM node with CentOS,

1. iptables support is enabled on the bridge (bridge-nf-call-iptables)
2. iptables rules can be used to log the data, 2 chain rules one for incoming and one for outgoing
3. then a bash script is used to extract the data/store the data
4. iptables counter is flushed (iptables -Z iirc)

I'm pretty new to SmartOS and have tried looking up a way to install iptables (which I assume isn't possible since this is based off solaris?) so what would be the best way to get a similar setup going on SmartOS?

Comment: Why would you use KVM on a non-native system anyway?

Comment: You're running Centos on KVM inside SmartOS right? So you should just install iptables as normal inside the KVM. If you're looking for SmartOS version of iptables you're looking for http://blog.smartcore.net.au/smartos-zone-firewall-guide/